# Suddenly my Rubymine's database window is not showing for any rails app!. How to bring it back?

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

I have search a lot on google for solution.But I have not found any resources similar to my problem.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Junan, Let me know if that solved your problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
View > Tool Windows > Database
```

[image]

[For more information see here.](https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/help/database-tool-window.html)

#### Update:

You should check whether `Database Tools` and `SQL` plugin is enabled in your RubyMine.

Comment: But in my IDE, there is no database option! http://i.imgur.com/TNW3XWS.png @K M Rakibul Islam

Comment: Was it there before? Can you try exit the RubyMine and then re-start again?

Comment: I did not check it before but before today database window always showed in right side of the IDE. I did it ...even restart the machine but result is same

Comment: This is very weird. I think you should uninstall and re-install it. Possibly another version. I use `7.0.4`
see if that works.

Comment: My version is 7.1.2 .... Ya may be I should re-install it. Anyway thank you bhaiya for your time.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have any other question now, or later.

Comment: @JunanChakma awesome :-) I have updated my answer for future users.